# Parse and expand JSON data that currently embedded within a Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

Essentially I have raw data that has been pulled from a certain Weather API. Through an SQL query, the data is formatted into a data frame with columns: latitudes (lats), longitudes (lngs), date, and "blob."

The blob is JSON data that is nested in 2 layers. The data as you will see below starts off with a summary for the entire day "daily" at the first layer, and 24 hourly summaries under "hourly" at the second layer.

```
lats    lngs    date            blob
-46     168     2015-01-31      {"daily": {"apparentTemperatureMaxTime": 1422680400, "temperatureMax": 21.33, "temperatureMinTime": 1422615600, "temperatureMin": 16.06, "icon": "clear-day", "apparentTemperatureMax": 21.33, "summary": "Clear throughout the day.", "pressure": 1010.91, "temperatureMaxTime": 1422680400, "humidity": 0.81, "dewPoint": 15.14, "sunsetTime": 1422692673, "precipType": "rain", "windSpeed": 3.01, "apparentTemperatureMin": 16.06, "sunriseTime": 1422639631, "apparentTemperatureMinTime": 1422615600, "time": 1422615600, "visibility": 16.09, "windBearing": 75, "moonPhase": 0.38}, "hourly": [{"apparentTemperature": 16.06, "windSpeed": 4.29, "icon": "clear-night", "temperature": 16.06, "summary": "Clear", "pressure": 1015.05, "humidity": 0.89, "dewPoint": 14.23, "precipType": "rain", "time": 1422615600, "visibility": 16.09, "windBearing": 97}, {"apparentTemperature": 16.17, "windSpeed": 4.22, "icon": "clear-night", "temperature": 16.17, "summary": "Clear", "pressure": 1014.91, "humidity": 0.88, "dewPoint": 14.19, "precipType": "rain", "time": 1422619200, "visibility": 16.09, "windBearing": 94}, {"apparentTemperature": 16.27, "windSpeed": 4.09, "icon": "clear-night", "temperature": 16.27, "summary": "Clear", "pressure": 1014.51, "humidity": 0.87, "dewPoint": 14.14, "precipType": "rain", "time": 1422622800, "visibility": 16.09, "windBearing": 87}, {"apparentTemperature": 16.36, "windSpeed": 4, "icon": "clear-night", "temperature": 16.36, "summary": "Clear", "pressure": 1013.94, "humidity": 0.86, "dewPoint": 14.09, "precipType": "rain", "time": 1422626400, "visibility": 16.09, "windBearing": 80}, {"apparentTemperature": 16.4, "windSpeed": 3.9, "icon": "clear-night", "temperature": 16.4, "summary": "Clear", "pressure": 1013.43, "humidity": 0.86, "dewPoint": 14.07, "precipType": "rain", "time": 1422630000, "visibility": 16.09, "windBearing": 75},
```

Below is a dict of 2 sets of data for 1 date.

```
{'lat': {0: -45, 1: -45}, 'lng': {0: 169, 1: 170}, 'date': {0: datetime.date(2015, 1, 1), 1: datetime.date(2015, 1, 1)}, 'blob': {0: {'daily': {'apparentTemperatureMaxTime': 1420088400, 'temperatureMax': 19.06, 'temperatureMinTime': 1420045200, 'temperatureMin': 7.86, 'icon': 'clear-day', 'apparentTemperatureMax': 19.06, 'summary': 'Clear throughout the day.', 'pressure': 1013.08, 'temperatureMaxTime': 1420088400, 'humidity': 0.61, 'dewPoint': 5.49, 'sunsetTime': 1420101288, 'precipType': 'rain', 'windSpeed': 3.18, 'apparentTemperatureMin': 6.76, 'sunriseTime': 1420045310, 'apparentTemperatureMinTime': 1420041600, 'time': 1420023600, 'visibility': 16, 'windBearing': 241, 'moonPhase': 0.36}, 'hourly': [{'apparentTemperature': 6.78, 'windSpeed': 6.98, 'icon': 'clear-night', 'temperature': 9.88, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1005.77, 'humidity': 0.81, 'dewPoint': 6.74, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420023600, 'visibility': 12.59, 'windBearing': 208}, {'apparentTemperature': 7.23, 'windSpeed': 4.95, 'icon': 'clear-night', 'temperature': 9.7, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1007.34, 'humidity': 0.81, 'dewPoint': 6.51, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420027200, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 217}, {'apparentTemperature': 7.19, 'windSpeed': 4.13, 'icon': 'clear-night', 'temperature': 9.39, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1008.35, 'humidity': 0.81, 'dewPoint': 6.29, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420030800, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 226}, {'apparentTemperature': 6.96, 'windSpeed': 3.77, 'icon': 'clear-night', 'temperature': 9.06, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1009.02, 'humidity': 0.82, 'dewPoint': 6.09, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420034400, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 235}, {'apparentTemperature': 6.79, 'windSpeed': 3.38, 'icon': 'clear-night', 'temperature': 8.76, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1009.81, 'humidity': 0.82, 'dewPoint': 5.83, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420038000, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 243}, {'apparentTemperature': 6.76, 'windSpeed': 2.56, 'icon': 'clear-night', 'temperature': 8.29, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1010.94, 'humidity': 0.82, 'dewPoint': 5.33, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420041600, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 249}, {'apparentTemperature': 7.09, 'windSpeed': 1.6, 'icon': 'clear-night', 'temperature': 7.86, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1012.19, 'humidity': 0.81, 'dewPoint': 4.76, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420045200, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 255}, {'apparentTemperature': 8.08, 'windSpeed': 1.15, 'icon': 'clear-day', 'temperature': 8.08, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1013.28, 'humidity': 0.78, 'dewPoint': 4.47, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420048800, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 265}, {'apparentTemperature': 8.95, 'windSpeed': 1.62, 'icon': 'clear-day', 'temperature': 9.49, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1014.17, 'humidity': 0.71, 'dewPoint': 4.59, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420052400, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 265}, {'apparentTemperature': 11.57, 'windSpeed': 2.55, 'icon': 'clear-day', 'temperature': 11.57, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1014.91, 'humidity': 0.63, 'dewPoint': 4.76, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420056000, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 261}, {'apparentTemperature': 13.41, 'windSpeed': 3.3, 'icon': 'clear-day', 'temperature': 13.41, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1015.39, 'humidity': 0.56, 'dewPoint': 4.79, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420059600, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 260}, {'apparentTemperature': 14.68, 'windSpeed': 3.65, 'icon': 'clear-day', 'temperature': 14.68, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1015.52, 'humidity': 0.52, 'dewPoint': 4.83, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420063200, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 260}, {'apparentTemperature': 15.71, 'windSpeed': 3.81, 'icon': 'clear-day', 'temperature': 15.71, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1015.39, 'humidity': 0.49, 'dewPoint': 4.96, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420066800, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 261}, {'apparentTemperature': 16.59, 'windSpeed': 3.77, 'icon': 'clear-day', 'temperature': 16.59, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1015.18, 'humidity': 0.47, 'dewPoint': 5.17, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420070400, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 260}, {'apparentTemperature': 17.33, 'windSpeed': 3.4, 'icon': 'clear-day', 'temperature': 17.33, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1014.95, 'humidity': 0.46, 'dewPoint': 5.55, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420074000, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 253}, {'apparentTemperature': 17.92, 'windSpeed': 2.94, 'icon': 'clear-day', 'temperature': 17.92, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1014.64, 'humidity': 0.46, 'dewPoint': 6.06, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420077600, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 240}, {'apparentTemperature': 18.36, 'windSpeed': 2.81, 'icon': 'clear-day', 'temperature': 18.36, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1014.31, 'humidity': 0.46, 'dewPoint': 6.39, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420081200, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 229}, {'apparentTemperature': 18.78, 'windSpeed': 3.08, 'icon': 'clear-day', 'temperature': 18.78, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1013.85, 'humidity': 0.44, 'dewPoint': 6.43, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420084800, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 227}, {'apparentTemperature': 19.06, 'windSpeed': 3.5, 'icon': 'clear-day', 'temperature': 19.06, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1013.37, 'humidity': 0.43, 'dewPoint': 6.29, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420088400, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 230}, {'apparentTemperature': 18.78, 'windSpeed': 3.76, 'icon': 'clear-day', 'temperature': 18.78, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1013.31, 'humidity': 0.43, 'dewPoint': 6.06, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420092000, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 233}, {'apparentTemperature': 17.53, 'windSpeed': 3.78, 'icon': 'clear-day', 'temperature': 17.53, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1014.01, 'humidity': 0.45, 'dewPoint': 5.54, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420095600, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 238}, {'apparentTemperature': 15.72, 'windSpeed': 3.68, 'icon': 'clear-day', 'temperature': 15.72, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1015.13, 'humidity': 0.48, 'dewPoint': 4.85, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420099200, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 244}, {'apparentTemperature': 14.18, 'windSpeed': 3.29, 'icon': 'clear-night', 'temperature': 14.18, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1016.13, 'humidity': 0.52, 'dewPoint': 4.51, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420102800, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 250}, {'apparentTemperature': 13.23, 'windSpeed': 2.39, 'icon': 'clear-night', 'temperature': 13.23, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1016.88, 'humidity': 0.57, 'dewPoint': 4.88, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420106400, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 255}]}, 1: {'daily': {'apparentTemperatureMaxTime': 1420081200, 'temperatureMax': 18.18, 'temperatureMinTime': 1420045200, 'temperatureMin': 8.68, 'icon': 'clear-day', 'apparentTemperatureMax': 18.18, 'summary': 'Clear throughout the day.', 'pressure': 1013.16, 'temperatureMaxTime': 1420081200, 'humidity': 0.63, 'dewPoint': 6.58, 'sunsetTime': 1420101048, 'precipType': 'rain', 'windSpeed': 1.6, 'apparentTemperatureMin': 7.85, 'sunriseTime': 1420045069, 'apparentTemperatureMinTime': 1420041600, 'time': 1420023600, 'visibility': 16.06, 'windBearing': 232, 'moonPhase': 0.36}, 'hourly': [{'apparentTemperature': 11.77, 'windSpeed': 6.44, 'icon': 'clear-night', 'temperature': 11.77, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1004.34, 'humidity': 0.77, 'dewPoint': 7.78, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420023600, 'visibility': 14.73, 'windBearing': 222}, {'apparentTemperature': 11.13, 'windSpeed': 5.33, 'icon': 'clear-night', 'temperature': 11.13, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1006.11, 'humidity': 0.78, 'dewPoint': 7.52, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420027200, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 218}, {'apparentTemperature': 10.48, 'windSpeed': 4.48, 'icon': 'clear-night', 'temperature': 10.48, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1007.3, 'humidity': 0.79, 'dewPoint': 6.95, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420030800, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 218}, {'apparentTemperature': 8.01, 'windSpeed': 3.65, 'icon': 'clear-night', 'temperature': 9.87, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1008.18, 'humidity': 0.78, 'dewPoint': 6.27, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420034400, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 222}, {'apparentTemperature': 7.87, 'windSpeed': 2.9, 'icon': 'clear-night', 'temperature': 9.42, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1009.12, 'humidity': 0.78, 'dewPoint': 5.77, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420038000, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 228}, {'apparentTemperature': 7.85, 'windSpeed': 2.18, 'icon': 'clear-night', 'temperature': 8.98, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1010.33, 'humidity': 0.79, 'dewPoint': 5.55, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420041600, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 235}, {'apparentTemperature': 8.07, 'windSpeed': 1.56, 'icon': 'clear-night', 'temperature': 8.68, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1011.62, 'humidity': 0.8, 'dewPoint': 5.5, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420045200, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 247}, {'apparentTemperature': 9.08, 'windSpeed': 1.31, 'icon': 'clear-day', 'temperature': 9.08, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1012.76, 'humidity': 0.79, 'dewPoint': 5.6, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420048800, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 265}, {'apparentTemperature': 10.71, 'windSpeed': 1.57, 'icon': 'clear-day', 'temperature': 10.71, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1013.74, 'humidity': 0.72, 'dewPoint': 5.8, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420052400, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 277}, {'apparentTemperature': 13.04, 'windSpeed': 2.04, 'icon': 'clear-day', 'temperature': 13.04, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1014.59, 'humidity': 0.62, 'dewPoint': 5.82, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420056000, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 280}, {'apparentTemperature': 15, 'windSpeed': 2.33, 'icon': 'clear-day', 'temperature': 15, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1015.2, 'humidity': 0.53, 'dewPoint': 5.62, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420059600, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 280}, {'apparentTemperature': 16.19, 'windSpeed': 2.35, 'icon': 'clear-day', 'temperature': 16.19, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1015.48, 'humidity': 0.49, 'dewPoint': 5.54, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420063200, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 277}, {'apparentTemperature': 17.03, 'windSpeed': 2.2, 'icon': 'clear-day', 'temperature': 17.03, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1015.53, 'humidity': 0.47, 'dewPoint': 5.64, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420066800, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 271}, {'apparentTemperature': 17.63, 'windSpeed': 1.76, 'icon': 'clear-day', 'temperature': 17.63, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1015.51, 'humidity': 0.46, 'dewPoint': 5.91, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420070400, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 263}, {'apparentTemperature': 18.01, 'windSpeed': 0.8, 'icon': 'clear-day', 'temperature': 18.01, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1015.5, 'humidity': 0.47, 'dewPoint': 6.51, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420074000, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 236}, {'apparentTemperature': 18.17, 'windSpeed': 1.01, 'icon': 'clear-day', 'temperature': 18.17, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1015.42, 'humidity': 0.49, 'dewPoint': 7.28, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420077600, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 134}, {'apparentTemperature': 18.18, 'windSpeed': 1.86, 'icon': 'clear-day', 'temperature': 18.18, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1015.32, 'humidity': 0.51, 'dewPoint': 7.79, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420081200, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 118}, {'apparentTemperature': 18.16, 'windSpeed': 1.94, 'icon': 'clear-day', 'temperature': 18.16, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1015.08, 'humidity': 0.51, 'dewPoint': 7.83, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420084800, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 118}, {'apparentTemperature': 17.98, 'windSpeed': 1.56, 'icon': 'clear-day', 'temperature': 17.98, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1014.82, 'humidity': 0.51, 'dewPoint': 7.63, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420088400, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 123}, {'apparentTemperature': 17.43, 'windSpeed': 1.06, 'icon': 'clear-day', 'temperature': 17.43, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1014.82, 'humidity': 0.52, 'dewPoint': 7.46, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420092000, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 136}, {'apparentTemperature': 16.22, 'windSpeed': 0.63, 'icon': 'clear-day', 'temperature': 16.22, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1015.3, 'humidity': 0.56, 'dewPoint': 7.32, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420095600, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 191}, {'apparentTemperature': 14.62, 'windSpeed': 1.22, 'icon': 'clear-day', 'temperature': 14.62, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1016.05, 'humidity': 0.61, 'dewPoint': 7.07, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420099200, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 249}, {'apparentTemperature': 13.17, 'windSpeed': 1.68, 'icon': 'clear-night', 'temperature': 13.17, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1016.68, 'humidity': 0.66, 'dewPoint': 6.86, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420102800, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 262}, {'apparentTemperature': 11.98, 'windSpeed': 1.21, 'icon': 'clear-night', 'temperature': 11.98, 'summary': 'Clear', 'pressure': 1017.11, 'humidity': 0.71, 'dewPoint': 6.86, 'precipType': 'rain', 'time': 1420106400, 'visibility': 16.09, 'windBearing': 271}]}}}
```

Right now, so that I can eventually turn it into a function, I have been doing it step by step hoping to get all the steps, but I've been getting stuck with some of the JSON/DICT conversion of the nested data.

The goal is to breakdown the blob so that the 24 hours are pulled out and separated while keeping them paired to the original lats, lgns, and date.

From the SQL query mentioned, I already get the data in a 4 column dataframe shown above. I am able to isolate the "blob" using:

```
test_df = temps_df.iloc[:,3]
```

and get an output of:

```
id   blob
0    {'daily': {'apparentTemperatureMaxTime': 14215...
```

I then tried to normalize this using:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_normalize(test_df))
```

And it breaks it down one layer into a dataframe with all the daily conditions (trash), and then all the 24 hourly conditions in another bob (there's no neat way of putting this 22 column table in here.

Trying to take it one depth further, I tried:

```
hourly_df = json_normalize(data=test_df, record_path = 'hourly')
```

But this gives me:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

```
temps_df = db.get_historical_weather(lats, lngs, start_date, end_date)
temps_df.head()

lat     lng     date    blob
0   -45     170     2015-01-18  {'daily': {'apparentTemperatureMaxTime': 14215...
1   -45     170     2015-01-19  {'daily': {'apparentTemperatureMaxTime': 14216...
2   -45     170     2015-01-20  {'daily': {'apparentTemperatureMaxTime': 14217...
3   -45     170     2015-01-21  {'daily': {'apparentTemperatureMaxTime': 14218...
4   -45     170     2015-01-22  {'daily': {'apparentTemperatureMaxTime': 14219...

test_df = temps_df.iloc[:,3]
test_df.head()

0    {'daily': {'apparentTemperatureMaxTime': 14215...
1    {'daily': {'apparentTemperatureMaxTime': 14216...
2    {'daily': {'apparentTemperatureMaxTime': 14217...
3    {'daily': {'apparentTemperatureMaxTime': 14218...
4    {'daily': {'apparentTemperatureMaxTime': 14219...
Name: blob, dtype: object

test_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_normalize(test_df))
test_df.head()

daily.apparentTemperatureMax    daily.apparentTemperatureMaxTime    daily.apparentTemperatureMin    daily.apparentTemperatureMinTime    daily.dewPoint  daily.humidity  daily.icon  daily.moonPhase     daily.precipType    daily.pressure  ...     daily.sunsetTime    daily.temperatureMax    daily.temperatureMaxTime    daily.temperatureMin    daily.temperatureMinTime    daily.time  daily.visibility    daily.windBearing   daily.windSpeed     hourly
0   21.17   1421542800  12.39   1421514000  10.78   0.74    clear-day   0.90    rain    995.62  ...     1421569528  21.17   1421542800  12.39   1421514000  1421492400  14.27   232     1.13    [{'apparentTemperature': 14.21, 'windSpeed': 0...
1   15.69   1421632800  9.66    1421600400  9.34    0.79    clear-day   0.94    rain    1000.24     ...     1421655887  15.69   1421632800  9.66    1421600400  1421578800  13.74   223     0.53    [{'apparentTemperature': 11.41, 'windSpeed': 1...
2   16.73   1421719200  8.53    1421686800  7.86    0.74    clear-day   0.97    rain    1014.10     ...     1421742244  16.73   1421719200  8.53    1421686800  1421665200  15.85   208     1.94    [{'apparentTemperature': 10.08, 'windSpeed': 1...

hourly_df = json_normalize(data=test_df, record_path = 'hourly')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-dd6793be4e4c> in <module>()
----> 1 hourly_df = json_normalize(data=test_df, record_path = 'hourly')

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/normalize.py in json_normalize(data, record_path, meta, meta_prefix, record_prefix, errors, sep)
    260                 records.extend(recs)
    261 
--> 262     _recursive_extract(data, record_path, {}, level=0)
    263 
    264     result = DataFrame(records)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/normalize.py in _recursive_extract(data, path, seen_meta, level)
    236         else:
    237             for obj in data:
--> 238                 recs = _pull_field(obj, path[0])
    239 
    240                 # For repeating the metadata later

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/normalize.py in _pull_field(js, spec)
    183                 result = result[field]
    184         else:
--> 185             result = result[spec]
    186 
    187         return result

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Again, I'm trying this line by line hoping to get one grand function that produces the result I'm looking for. In the end, I would be looking for a data frame that just has...

```
    lat     lng    date          hour    temp
0   -45     170    2015-01-28    0       10
1   -45     170    2015-01-28    1       10
2   -45     170    2015-01-28    2       10
3   -45     170    2015-01-28    3       10
4   -45     170    2015-01-28    4       10
```

So, it would show all 24 hours of data for one date of one lat and lng, then move on to the next date for that lat and lng, until it goes through all the dates in the frame, then it would increment to the lat lng pair.

Comment: Can you please post the output of the following: ```print(test_df.head().to_dict())```? It allows users to easily recreate your DataFrame, and it will make it easier for people to help you!

Comment: At what step would you like to see that Ben?

Comment: I just need a way to get part of your dataframe in a form where I can easily create my own. Its hard to test otherwise.

Comment: Ben, ideally, how many lats/lngs would you like to see? If I give you a dict of a 5 entry head, I exceed the character limit for the post.

Comment: A single row is fine, so you can do head(1).

Comment: Added the dict of one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

#from your data
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#make the entire df a json file
df_json = df.to_json(orient = 'records', date_format='iso')

#use json_normalize to read in your json file, look at the hourly dict, and attach lat, lng and date.
df2 = json_normalize(json.loads(df_json), record_path = ['blob' , 'hourly'] , meta = ['lat', 'lng', 'date'])

#look at only the columns you want
df3 = df2.reindex(['lat', 'lng', 'date','temperature'], axis = 1)

#repeat 0-23 for the lenght of the df (since the time column in hourly isnt quite right, look at your dict that you posted)
df3['hour'] = (np.arange(0, 24).tolist())*(int(len(df3)/24))

df3.head()

    lat lng            date          temperature     hour
0   -44 169   2015-09-28T00:00:00.000Z   8.62         0
1   -44 169   2015-09-28T00:00:00.000Z   8.34         1
2   -44 169   2015-09-28T00:00:00.000Z   7.30         2
3   -44 169   2015-09-28T00:00:00.000Z   5.94         3
4   -44 169   2015-09-28T00:00:00.000Z   4.88         4
```

The easiest way to do this is export the data to json, then read it in with json_normalize. The time column in the dict isnt quite right, so I created my own hour column (but if they are all full days then this will work fine).

```
#Output with two rows:

df3.iloc[np.r_[0:5, -5:0]]

    lat lng          date           temperature hour
0   -45 169 2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z    9.88    0
1   -45 169 2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z    9.70    1
2   -45 169 2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z    9.39    2
3   -45 169 2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z    9.06    3
4   -45 169 2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z    8.76    4
43  -45 170 2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z    17.43   19
44  -45 170 2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z    16.22   20
45  -45 170 2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z    14.62   21
46  -45 170 2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z    13.17   22
47  -45 170 2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z    11.98   23
```

Comment: Got an error in implementation...
`temps_json = temps_df.to_json(orient = 'records', date_format='iso')
temps_hourly_df = json_normalize(json.loads(temps_json), record_path = ['blob', 'hourly'], meta = ['lat', 'lng', 'date'])

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: There seems to be an error with your temps_df. When I run your code but substitute temps_df with my df it worked fine. Try to import your own data into a new df with your own dict as I did and see what happens.

Comment: I did as you suggested, converting my data to a dict then back into a dataframe, but the same thing happened.
Might it be because I have multiple lats and lngs while what I provided only has one?

Comment: Why don't you edit your dict that you left me for 2 rows with different lat/longs and I can see if it works on my end, at the same time run my code with only the dict you posted and see if that works. Also did you get the same error when you did that?

Comment: 2 rows of data as a dict added. What I did was took the dataframe I had (temps_df) converted it to a dict so that it emulated what I gave you. I ran your lines as shown above and got the same error. I'll try again now to see if I messed something up.

Comment: I just tried it with the two lines, and it works as it should. Whats your pandas version? if its not the most updated one, I suggest updating.

Comment: I'm on v0.23.4, so the latest full release if I'm correct.

Comment: v0.24.2 is the latest. Im only suggesting because I found this https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22706, which is the error code your receiving, and was fixed in v0.24.

Comment: Panda's update worked perfectly. Thank you Ben, you were an immense help. (Side note: Needed to import numpy lol)